# t sql sort by calculated column

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by, sql-server-2014

I'm on T-SQL 2014 and try to order products by their price. Now here is the problem: the price is a calculated field. Eg. I have created a function which evaluates a number of pricing rules (maybe about 4 tables with each about 4,000,000 records combined with JOINs to fit to the current login) and returns the users price for the product. While this is OK if I just want to return the price for a limited number of products it is way to slow if I want to sort by this.

I was thinking about having an additional table like UserProductPrice which will get calculated in the background but this will obviously not always have the correct price in it as the rules etc. could change in between the calculation.

Any suggestion on how I could sort by the price would be most appreciated.

Comment: You can use your background price table and keep it update using triggers. Now if you want tips for your slow query show us the db schema, the query and a explain plan

Comment: you can always try `select * into #tmp from query`  then `select * from #tmp order by price`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ROW_NUMBER() function and place this into a temp table:

```
SELECT
Product,
dbo.ufnPrice(Price) as Price,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY dbo.ufnPrice(Price) DESC) AS Ranking
INTO #Products
FROM dbo.Products

SELECT
Product,
Price,
FROM #Products
WHERE Ranking = 1

DROP TABLE #Products
```

Should give you what you need.